# Basic iOS issues

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, tableview

I am trying to to complete the 'Your Second iOS App' tutorial from the apple developer program. It is a basic tableView app. My problem is that the app is building successfully and without warnings, however I cannot get the detail view to segue from the master view. I have copied and pasted both the segue identifier and the code that apple has provided. The segue is using push and I have deleted it and tried again several times. I am testing the app in the simulator.

1. How can I tell if a segue is working?
2. Every time I copy/paste my code from Xcode into the stack overflow question text area, I get warnings at the bottom saying that code must be indented by 4 spaces??? Does this mean I have to go line-by-line indenting code?? I did the control + k and pasted in the highlighted area, however I still got the warning??
3. When running the simulator and looking at it, I'm trying to use a disclosure indicator by clicking on it, do I have to push something special like control = click or command = click, etc. ?

Here is the code for BirdsMasterViewController.m file:

```
            //
            //  BirdsMasterViewController.m
            //  BirdWatching
            //
            //  Created by David Hall on 11/13/12.
            //  Copyright (c) 2012 David Hall. All rights reserved.
            //

            #import "BirdsMasterViewController.h"

            #import "BirdsDetailViewController.h"

            #import "BirdSightingDataController.h"

            #import "BirdSighting.h"

            /*
            @interface BirdsMasterViewController () {
                NSMutableArray *_objects;
            }
            @end
            */
            @implementation BirdsMasterViewController

            - (void)awakeFromNib
            {
                [super awakeFromNib];

                self.dataController = [[BirdSightingDataController alloc] init];
            }

            - (void)viewDidLoad
            {
                [super viewDidLoad];
                // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
            /*
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

                UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
                self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
            */
             }

            - (void)viewDidUnload
            {
                [super viewDidUnload];
                // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
            }

            - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
            {
                return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
            }

            /*- (void)insertNewObject:(id)sender
            {
                if (!_objects) {
                    _objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                }
                [_objects insertObject:[NSDate date] atIndex:0];
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
                [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            }
            */
            #pragma mark - Table View

            - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
            {
                return 1;
            }

            - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
            {
                return [self.dataController countOfList];
            }

            - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BirdSightingCell";

                static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;
                if (formatter == nil)
                {
                    formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                    [formatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
                }

                UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
                BirdSighting *sightingAtIndex = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                [[cell textLabel] setText:sightingAtIndex.name];
                [[cell detailTextLabel] setText:[formatter stringFromDate:(NSDate *)sightingAtIndex.date]];


                return cell;
            }

            - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
                return NO;
            }

            /*- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
                    [_objects removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
                    // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
                }
            }
            */
            /*
            // Override to support rearranging the table view.
            - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
            {
            }
            */

            /*
            // Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
            - (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
            {
                // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
                return YES;
            }
            */

            - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
            {
                if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowSightingDetails"]) {
                    BirdsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
                    detailViewController.sighting = [self.dataController objectInListAtIndex:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];

                }
            }

            @end
```

And here is the code for the BirdsDetailViewController.m

```
        //
        //  BirdSightingDataController.m
        //  BirdWatching
        //
        //  Created by David Hall on 11/25/12.
        //  Copyright (c) 2012 David Hall. All rights reserved.
        //

        #import "BirdSightingDataController.h"
        #import "BirdSighting.h"

        @interface BirdSightingDataController ()

        - (void)initializeDefaultDataList;

        @end

        @implementation BirdSightingDataController

        - (void)initializeDefaultDataList
        {
            NSMutableArray *sightingList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            self.masterBirdSightingList = sightingList;

            BirdSighting *sighting;

            NSDate *today = [NSDate date];

            sighting = [[BirdSighting alloc] initWithName:@"Pigeon" location:@"Everywhere" date:today];

            [self addBirdSightingWithSighting:sighting];

        }

        - (void)setMasterBirdSightingList:(NSMutableArray *)newList
        {
            if (_masterBirdSightingList != newList)
            {
                _masterBirdSightingList = [newList mutableCopy];
            }

        }

        - (id)init
        {
            if (self = [super init])
            {
                [self initializeDefaultDataList];

                return self;
            }

            return nil;
        }

        - (NSUInteger)countOfList
        {
            return [self.masterBirdSightingList count];
        }

        - (BirdSighting *)objectInListAtIndex:(NSUInteger)theIndex
        {
            return [self.masterBirdSightingList objectAtIndex:theIndex];
        }

        - (void)addBirdSightingWithSighting:(BirdSighting *)sighting
        {
            [self.masterBirdSightingList addObject:sighting];
        }









        @end
```

David Hall

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! However, your question isn't very clear at the moment. You might want to supply some code. Also, your third question is very confusing. I would suggest rewriting your answer in a clear and concise manner.

Are you using storyboards?

Comment: yes I am using storyboard. If you'll read question #2, I state that I have tried to copy/paste my code into the question, however stack overflow gives me a warning that states that I must have 4 spaces on my lines of code??? Does this mean that I have to go line by line and add 4 spaces? I even hit control + k like the warning suggest and paste my code into the highlighted area, however it STILL gives me a warning.

Comment: See Abizern 1st answer, as it explains how to format the text.

Comment: Hi. This isn't an answer to your question (I haven't even read it). But for starting out in Objective-C I think the best book is by Stephen Kochan 'Programming in Objective-C' - read that after going through the beginners tutorial on Ray Wenderlich's blog (google it). You'll be away in no time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's working when it works. But without knowing more about what you are doing it's hard to give you an answer.
2. Highlight the code in the textbox and then click on this button.

   [image]

   It will indent the code correctly for you.
3. I can't make sense of this question.

**Edited to add**

(After seeing a copy of the project that the OP mailed me)

Your segue wasn't wired up properly.

The segue is supposed to go from the cell to the next view controller, because the point is to transition on a cell click. Your segue is wired up from the controller to the detail view controller. In your project - right click on your view controller and you'll see the segue is manually connected. But right clicking on the cell doesn't show a segue connection.

Delete the current segue and recreate it, this time by control-dragging from the cell to the next view controller. You can then double check the connection by right clicking on the cell and making sure that the segue is connected.

It should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. If the segue is supposed to transition from your table to a detail view, and if you can't get to the detail view from the table, then your segue isn't working.
2. You can use the code sample button at the top of the SO editor, or you can select the code in your text editor and indent it before you copy it. For example, in Xcode it's easy to select the code, hit Command-], and copy. Then just paste into the SO editor.
3. Please edit your question so that it makes sense. However, I think you might be asking something along the lines of how to push a view controller from your table. If you're using a segue, and if you've created the segue in your storyboard and it's connected to both the source and destination view controllers, then you can send `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to your table's view controller. That is, your table view controller's `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method should call `-performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` and specify the identifier for the segue leading from the table view controller to the detail view controller. It doesn't matter whether you're using the simulator or running your app on a real device.

Comment: 1. I have deleted and added the segue several times. The style is Push and the identifier name matches the name in my performSegueWithIdentifier method. I tried to add a break in my code at the performSegueWithIdentifier method, but it never breaks. Is there a way to test it in the bug tester? Everything seems to work except the segue.

Comment: So put the breakpoint just before the call to `-performSegueWithIdentifier:`, perhaps at the very beginning of your `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Do you hit the breakpoint? If no, make sure that your view controller is set as the table's delegate.

Comment: Don't repost your question -- it'll get closed as an exact duplicate. Edit this question instead

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me on such a simple problem. I am trying to put a breakpoint to help, but the apple tutorial never calls for a tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. However there is a objectInListAtIndex: method. Here is the link to the BirdsMasterViewController.m apple tutorial - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CustomizingMasterView/CustomizingMasterView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH4-SW4

Answer (score 0):

See the other answers from Caleb and Abizem regarding 1. and 2. If I understood your question No 3 correctly, then the answer is no. You do not have to press something in particular in the simulator when you want to select a table row or the detail desclosure indicator. Just click on those items that you would tap on your device too. If it does not segue then the chances are that its not the simulator causing the problem :)